# How to loop two bootstrap columns using HEREDOC

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to loop through products and display them in two bootstrap columns. Obviously the way I have it now won't work as the output is:

```
    Apple           Apple
    Banana          Banana
    Grapes          Grapes
    Strawberry      Strawberry
```

Whereas it should look like:

```
Apple           Banana
Grapes          Strawberry


function bootloop($link) {

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `prod_name` FROM `products`");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if($result) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $prod_name = sanitize($row['prod_name']);

            $bootloop = <<<LOOPCOLUMNS

            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">{$prod_name}</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">{$prod_name}</div>

LOOPCOLUMNS;
            echo $bootloop;
        }
    }

    $stmt->close();
}



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php bootloop($link); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to just have one `<div class="col-md-6 text-center">{$prod_name}</div>` in the loop :)

Comment: Oh, right. Perhaps I was in the sun too long today.. :P

Comment: I can't seem to choose your comment as an answer. Perhaps repost the code minus the one col-md-6 line.

Comment: Yeah, can do. That being said bootstrap columns should be wrapped in rows so that they are styled properly. Would you like me to show you a way you can do that?

Comment: Yes, please! That would be much appreciated.

Comment: Oh, wait. I think I did do that but not within the HEREDOC. I have it when I call the function. 

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <?php bootloop($link); ?>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: I edited my original post to show you what I mean.

Comment: You should always try and wrap columns that are going to make up one row in a `class="row"` as it provides clears for your elements and if you end up having columns that are different heights you will potentially start having problems as they won't be getting cleared. As you're only going to be having one word in your columns I doubt you have an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to group your array values for your rows you could use `array_chunk()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Also, as you're not needing to store the `html` for later and the lines are fairly small I would just use `echo` instead `HEREDOC` as I find it more readable. Obviously, you don't have to do this if you don't want to.

You would then have something like:

```
function bootloop($link)
{

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `prod_name` FROM `products`");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($result) {
        $prod_names = [];

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $prod_names[] = sanitize($row['prod_name']);
        }

        foreach (array_chunk($prod_names, 2) as $chunks) : ?>
            <div class="row">
                <?php foreach ($chunks as $prod_name) : ?>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <?php echo $prod_name ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach;
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't like the formatting of the foreach loops
            above with the multiple opening and closing php tags you could do:

```
foreach (array_chunk($prod_names, 2) as $chunks) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach ($chunks as $prod_name) {
        echo "<div class='col-md-6 text-center'>$prod_name</div>";
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

**EDIT**

If you're wanting to get the id for a product you would:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `id`, `prod_name` FROM `products`");

$products = [];

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $products[] = [
        'id'   => $row['id'],
        'name' => sanitize($row['prod_name']),
    ];
}

foreach (array_chunk($products, 2) as $chunks) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    foreach ($chunks as $product) {
        echo "<div class='col-md-6 text-center'>{$product['id']} {$product['name']}</div>";
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

In the above I now storing the data from each row in an array (I've also changed `$prod_name(s)` to be `$product(s)` to be more appropriate). When trying to access an array value inside `""` you have to wrap the value in `{}`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks great, thanks! If you don't mind helping me a little further, how can I add another variable to this? Like if I also wanted $prod_id as well as the existing $prod_name.

Comment: @Jonathan Just `id` or will you be add more to it later?

Comment: @Jonathan Ok, and what does `sanitize()` do?

Comment: sanitize is just my helper function for htmlentities

`function sanitize($dirty) {
 return htmlentities($dirty, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
}`

Comment: Dude. You are a legend!

Comment: @Jonathan Glad I could help!

Comment: @Jonathan Also, have a look at some of these https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners You can almost definitely skip the first few lessons but there are some concepts in some of the later lessons you might find interesting.